# Finding the index place of substring in source string of replaced string

Tags: python, string

In Python, I have a first sting A, 
I do some replace command for A which changes the length of the string.
After all replaces I search for a special pattern in the string I find the place of it. I want to have the index of this substring in my first string A.
It is the first index of characters that changed of not and form the final found substring:
This is simple example of my work:

```
A = ' abc '
B = A
B = B.replace("a", "b")
B = B.replace("c", "bb")
print(B.find('bbbb'))

#my answer is but i don't know the first string that is changed:
print(A.find('abc'))
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I changed the example

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: to find the location of original substing of 'bbbb'  in the first string A. this is only a simple example. the replaces could be more complicated. the answer is written in the last line but we do'nt know the substring abc.